# Confusion over initializers when subclassing UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and trying to subclass UIView. So far I have something like this:

```
class Timer: UIView {

    let totalPoints: Int
    let timeLimit: Double
    var elapsedTime: Double?




    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.config()
    }

    //Only called in IB
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.config()
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }




}
```

I need to initialize totalPoints and timeLimit but I want to create a new initializer function `init(frame: CGRect, timeLimit: Double, elapsedTime: Double)`. Do I also need to init the vars in the base init function?

Answer (score 0):

```
init(frame: CGRect, timeLimit: Double, elapsedTime: Double) {
     Super.init(frame: frame)
     Self.timeLimit=timeLimit
     Self.elapsedTime=elapsedTime
}
```

Do you mean this?

Comment: This won't work, any constant members need to be initialized before the `super`call.

Comment: I wrote code with my app, when i come back to home I'll compile and tell you. But you can try to write a class like class SubTimer: Timer with my init

Answer (score 0):

A much used idiom is *not* to override `init...`, but rather to declare your properties as implicitly unwrapped e.g.,

```
let totalPoints: Int!
let timeLimit: Double!
var elapsedTime: Double?
```

and then set them at some point in the future before they are accessed. This is, in effect, a promise that you will initialise them in time. It is more usually implemented in the `UIViewController` rather than the `UIView`, since you can guarantee that `viewDidLoad` will be called early in the lifecycle allowing you to set them there, however setting them in `drawRect` would work.

To amplify - you only need to initialise non-optionals before `init` completes. Since these are optionals, you can leave them (as `nil`), and as they are implicitly unwrapped, you do not need to explicitly unwrap them when referencing them later. Just make sure you *have* set them before accessing them, as not doing so will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `super` initializer needs to pass along only the info needed by `super`. In your case you'd need to pass a `CGRect`. What you need to do then is before calling `super` to initialize your own instance variables. This also needs to be done in `initWithCoder:`.

```
class Timer: UIView {

    let totalPoints: Int
    let timeLimit: Double
    var elapsedTime: Double?

    init(frame: CGRect, totalPoints: Int, timeLimit: Double) {
        self.totalPoints = totalPoints
        self.timeLimit = timeLimit
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.config()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.totalPoints = 0
        self.timeLimit = 0
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func config() {
        // ...    
    }
}
```

More details about class initializers can be found on Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html.